# windows phone application development

Tags: windows, led

Is it possible to control LED's of a windows phone from a windows phone metro style application ?

I am just working on an application that will ON/oFF the LED . Does microsoft provide any APIs to ON/OFF the notification LED of the windows phone ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not supported as most Windows Phones (especially Nokia/Microsoft) don't contain notification LEDs.

However, according to [this link](http://www.theverge.com/2015/3/16/8223189/windows-10-for-phones-led-notifications), it looks like this will be a feature supported by future Windows 10 (phone) hardware.